# Gmail inserts <wbr> tags into links

Tags: c#, html, email, gmail

I'm trying to send an email that consists a link. But when I send it to gmail account it becomes broken with  tags. Email has the base64 encoding.

Here is my html:

```
<p>Hello!</p><p>Here is the link to account activation:</p><p><a href="http://www.example.com/admin/activate/f8ekrwef2rnkjsdnfksjdnfskjnu3">Link</a></p>
```

And in gmail my link is displaying as:

```
<a> 
"http://www.example.com/"
<wbr></wbr>
"admin/activate/"
<wbr></wbr>
"f8ekrwef2rnkjsdnfksjdnfskjnu3"
</a>
```

Can I prevent somehow insertion of these tags into my link by gmail?

Here is the full method with email generation:

```
private void ShareHtmlHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "My email example";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = 
        "Description for my email example";

    string htmlExample = "<p>Hello!</p><p>Here is the magnet link to requested torrent:</p><p><a href=\"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:539390D341F8C18400052ED905F77E48D6EBE40E&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A80%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fmgtracker.org%3A2710%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.best-torrents.net%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbt.careland.com.cn%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker1.wasabii.com.tw%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eddie4.nl%3A6969%2Fannounce&xc=TorrentRTSearch\">magnet:?xt=urn:btih:539390D341F8C18400052ED905F77E48D6EBE40E&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A80%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fmgtracker.org%3A2710%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.best-torrents.net%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbt.careland.com.cn%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker1.wasabii.com.tw%3A6969%2Fannounce&dn=Avatar+ECE+(2009)+%5B1080p%5D&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eddie4.nl%3A6969%2Fannounce&xc=TorrentRTSearch</a></p>";
    string htmlFormat = HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(htmlExample);
}
```

Comment: Why did you use C# tag? How are you sending the email?

Comment: Cause I'm trying to send it from my program that was written on C#. I've added full method with email generation to my question. Thank You

Comment: Your code won't even compile, because your string `htmlExample` is not even a valid string.

Comment: Sorry, I used just example of string in my question, because the real one is very long. Now changed it to real. Thank You

Comment: Did you encode your email as html? Did you try a "simpler" url? Does it happen just with links?

Comment: If you look at the wbr reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr), the wbr tag should not interfere with the link itself

Comment: Now I found some dependency. Gmail inserts wbr tags into link only if it has the magnet: protocol at the beginning. When I've changed protocol in my link to http:// - link is clickable and there are no wbr tags in it.